# View with extra column that appends column to zero-padded id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've created the following table (tb_company):

[image]

the next step was to create a view derived from tb_company, where the "id" column and "companyName" column were concatenated as "id_and_companyName" as follows:

[image]

The problem with all this is that I'm using the view table on a sharepoint application and when I display the data it gets ordered in the following way:

[image]

Basically this is a character/alphabetical ordering but this is not what I'm trying to achieve.

I would like to add some pre-string characters in the "id_and_companyName" column, so that I can get some thing like this

[image]

How can I achieve this by TSQL script? I would like to create a view with such column.
In this way I'll fix my sorting issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed from your question that you won't have `id` values more than 4 digits. If that is the case:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myview AS
  SELECT id, companyName, 
    id_and_companyName = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',4) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),id),4)
    + ' ' + companyName
  FROM dbo.tablename;
```

Otherwise, increase those instances of `4` to something else. Also, be sure to not bother storing your `ORDER BY` clause with the view definition itself; specify the ordering in the queries that reference the view.

You might also consider making this a computed column instead of calculating it in a view. This gives you other opportunities to dictate when this calculation takes place; at storage time or query time. E.g. you can persist and/or index the column.

Finally, if this is all just for sorting, I don't know why you can't just say:

```
ORDER BY id, companyName;
```

Or, if `id` is currently a string data type for some reason, you could change that, or use:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,id), companyName;
```

This has the potential to break if you have bad data in there (all the more reason to fix it).

Comment: Yes, sorting the table with just the id could have worked but my goal was to show in sharepoint just one column. Using the id column I was forced to show the “id” and “companyName” column. The only way to show both columns was to concatenate them, since concatenation creates a string and sharepoint will sort it based on the string. That said, your appended padded string solution is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

You can zero pad a number like so `RIGHT('00000' + CAST(id as VARCHAR), 5)`.

Comment: [I'd be very cautious about using `varchar` without defining a length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).